# Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference error. Trying to add object to array

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I'm trying to add a couple of ball objects to an array for creating some of them but it is giving me this error.

The error is at `ballArray.push(ball);`

The code:

```
override public function setup(): void {
        scoreTextField = new TextField();
        this.game.addChild(scoreTextField);

        player = new Sprite();
        player.addChild(this.game.resourceMap["player.png"]);
        this.game.addChild(player);
        player.x = 800 / 2 - 150;
        player.y = 640 - 220;
        timer = new Timer(interval);
        timer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, ballCreate);
        timer.start();

    }

    public function ballCreate(e: Event): void {
        var ball: Ball = new Ball(this);
        ballArray.push(ball);
    }
```

The Ball Code in case it helps:

```
public function Ball(gameState: GameState) {
        this.gameState = gameState;
        sprite = new Sprite();
        sprite.addChild(gameState.game.resourceMap["test2.png"]);
        sprite.x = Math.random() * 50;
        sprite.y = 600;
        gameState.game.addChild(sprite);

        sprite.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, update);

    }

    public function update(e: Event): void {
        if(vy > 2 && touched == false) {
            sprite.y -= vy;
            vy*=gravity;
            sprite.x += vx;
            trace(vy);
        } else {
            touched = true;
            sprite.y += vy;
            vy/=gravity;
            sprite.x += vx;
        }
    }
```

Hope I can get some help with this problem, I don't have much experience with as3 also.

Thank you for your time

Comment: It would help if you pointed out which line is throwing the error.  Guess, is that `game` is null/not populated.

Answer (score 0):

Enable debugging (from AS3 publish setting). This way you will see on which line the error is!

Comment: Edited with the debugging now

Comment: @BotMaster - I partly agree. The thing is that if he finds the line, the question will change to 'why this is not working', which is totally different, and the whole this question is truly low quality. The only good advise to give is to teach the person how to debug his code properly. And this becomes the only real answer, as nothing else would solve the 'problem', because the actual problem now is "I don't know what's going on with my code, help me!"...

Comment: It's really not that at all, I made this question because I had an unpredictable error, I started using flash just out oc curiosity, and I figured adding objects to an array was no problem since I had made it in other languages before. I do know what is going on in my code. Although I am having some difficulties that's why im posting this here. I updated the debugging and I am trying to fix the bug. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Well now it's obvious that `ballArray` is null (see error). Also, please check the FAQ how to ask question. Questions like 'why my code is not working' are no good here. There's special section about how to ask questions. Good luck!